# Send Regular Email using MailChimp in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I'm using "spatie/laravel-newsletter" to subscribe users on signup. That is working fine. But now we need to send email to users when they purchase anything from our website.

I'm not able to find a way how can we send emails like we are currently sending from Laravel code using Gmail account from MailChimp.

Any lead would be helpful, what needs to be done on MailChimp dashboard side, what package of laravel might be useful and how we can send emails with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `spatie/newsletter` package is only to send marketing emails from your laravel application. Mailchimp offers a separate PHP library https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-transactional-php that can be used to send transactional emails using Mailchimp.

The documentation on this package should show you exactly what you need to do on the Mailchimp Dashboard and how you configure your app to send an email through Mailchimp

Transactional Emails are emails that you send that are event based (purchases, user registrations, etc).

Promotional emails like Newsletters are part of marketing emails.

I hope that clarifies and helps with your email configuration on your Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link for and E-commerce store trigger email, which show mailchimp will automatically sends an email when customer purchases a product.

https://mailchimp.com/help/all-the-classic-automation-triggers/#heading+e-commerce

It also has all sorts of trigger, which will automatically send email. Choose which best suits your requirement.

Comment: thanks for replying, this doc doesn't have Laravel listed in it, which option I should follow, custom website?

Comment: You dont have to do anything from laravel code, you just have to add a customer to correct campaign, and rest your campaign will handle automatically. Please check the below links, and it will show you how to setup the campaign
[link](https://mailchimp.com/help/edit-automation-emails) and this [extra link](https://mailchimp.com/help/edit-an-active-classic-automation/)

Comment: I believe you will get your answers here, that how Mailchimp will do all the things.. All you have to do it, when customer purchases any product you need to add that customer email into an automated marketing campaign to send an email.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I'm checking these links and docs. Will get back to you.

Comment: Sure no problem Umair, I hope you get your answer, in case you dont find any help.. Let me know.. I will try to find the exact example which will help you for sure.